# EF update one row at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using ef in a webapi project.In function A,i change the property A of one entity,function B ,i change the property B. When i post to these at the same time, i found only one property has been modified, i'm sure posts all success, but how can i modify these 2.

```
 using (NielsenPMContext db = new NielsenPMContext())
    {
     var member = db.Members.Find(openid);
     member.A=a;
     db.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;

     db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: where is your function A and function B ? Can you put those also ?

Comment: @Sampath the answer below is what i mean, A&B are the same but change the different prop of the entity. I have solved it, ty too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one context in both methods. Also do not use `db.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;`, because it will generate update statement for all properties. use `db.Entry(member).Property("PropertyName").IsModified = true;` instead. If `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled == true`, and you get data from context to modify, then you do not need to use any of them.

```
public void FunctionA(DbContext context, int openid)
{
    var member = db.Members.Find(openid);
    member.A=a;
    db.Entry(member).Property("A").IsModified = true;
}

public void FunctionB(DbContext context, int openid)
{
    var member = db.Members.Find(openid);
    member.B=b;
    db.Entry(member).Property("B").IsModified = true;
}
```

Then call both of this methods and `SaveChanges` for one context, like:

```
using (NielsenPMContext db = new NielsenPMContext())
{
    FunctionA(db, openid);
    FunctionB(db, openid);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Note:** Do not be afraid using `Find` method twice, because entity framework will get it from local context instead of database after first time. Or it will be great to get member and send it to `FunctionA` and `FunctionB`. And I believe that, you have good reason to change `A` and `B` members in different methods.

Comment: Ty, I test the 'db.Entry(member).Property("PropertyName").IsModified = true;' ,it works for me,thank you so much!